# bigvideo.js looping issue

Tags: jquery

We have implemented this on a site, using the code of:

```
$(function() {

    // initialize BigVideo
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    BV.show(
        'resources/video/bg_grass.mp4',
        {altSource:'resources/video/bg_grass.ogg'});
});
```

The problem is the video does not loop - it just stops at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the documentation first. http://videojs.com/docs/options/
Because BigVideo.js is built on top of Video.js, you can use the Video.js api.
Put { "loop": "true" }

Comment: OK, so how would that be added to the code?

BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false},{loop:true});

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the ambient parameter and set the value to true, the video loops. It does not play sound though.

```
// initialize BigVideo
   BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
   BV.init();
   BV.show('resources/video/bg_grass.mp4',
   {altSource:'resources/video/bg_grass.ogg',ambient:true});
})
```

Comment: Wow excellent answer thank you. I was struggling with the syntax assuimng they were all JS parameters, but the 2nd param is a full JSON data-value pair array. The documentation is scattered a bit, however I really like this plugin. It is fantastic and aside from all the dependencies it's really easy to install.

Comment: where do you look up those options for bigvideo.js ?

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone else encounters this problem, I would like to add different solution.

Although the one above is correct, it takes away the sound and the controls.

If, instead of `ambient:true`, you would add `doLoop:true`, the video will loop and you will keep the sound and controls.

See the full code below;

```
$(function() {
   // initialize BigVideo
   var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
   BV.init();
   BV.show('resources/video/bg_grass.mp4',
   {altSource:'resources/video/bg_grass.ogg',doLoop:true});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by freakstyler, passing the `doLoop` option is the correct way to do this. However, I believe you have to pass the options to `$.BigVideo()` as shown here:

```
        var opts = {
            controls: false,
            doLoop: true
        }
        BV = new $.BigVideo(opts);
        BV.init();
        BV.show('vid/cycling2.mp4',{ambient: false});
```

Comment: where do you find the options for bigvideo.js? i can't seem to find the docs for it to show what kinds of options there are.

Comment: You can find them in the code for bigvideo: https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js/blob/master/lib/bigvideo.js#L27

Comment: Great answer - this is the way to setup the looping when multiple sources are used.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to include the three video types for maximum browser compatibility, do this:

```
   $(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({doLoop:true});
    BV.init();

    if (Modernizr.touch) {
        BV.show('img/fallleaves.jpg');
        } else {
            BV.show([ 
            { type: "video/mp4",  src: "vid/fallleaves.mp4" },
            { type: "video/webm", src: "vid/fallleaves.webm"},
            { type: "video/ogg",  src: "vid/fallleaves.ogg"}
            ]);
        }
```

});